# Calculating probability of success from dice rolls with rerolling

Tags: probability

Given the following rules:

- roll a six sided dice:

  - if it's 2 or up, you win.
  - if it's 1, you re-roll the dice but only win by getting a 6 on that new dice roll.

By drawing a tree, I've concluded that you have 6 chances out of 11 to win (I hope that's correct)

The problem is I can't figure out what the mathematical formula is for this problem and for a generalized problem (eg: 3+ on first dice, then 5+ on second dice).

Every time, I need to draw a tree to figure out the chances of the win outcome.

Comment: you didnt define what was asked...did you want the probability to win in 2 chances? in all cases its different, and is defined by gemoetric series (if you dont want to use tree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both case roll twice. Then you have $36$ possible outcomes $(i,j)$. There are $5\times 6 = 30$ outcomes $(i,j)$ where $i\geq2$ and $1$ outcome $(1,6)$. So in $30+1=31$ of them you win.

You are speaking of $6$ out of $11$ but note that the $6$-th (outcome $(1,6)$) does not have the same probability to happen as the others. It has probability $\dfrac{1}{36}$ while the others all have probability $\dfrac{1}{6}$.

If you win with $k+$ on the first roll and also with $n+$ on the second then there are $(7-k)\times 6$ outcomes $(i,j)$ with $i\geq k$ and $(k-1)\times (7-n)$ with $i<k$ and $j\geq n$. So the probability that someone wins becomes: $$\frac{(7-k)\times6+(k-1)\times(7-n)}{36}$$